# How to find object in multiple sub objects

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have three Models : Product, Category and Event,

these are my models

**product.js**

```
 var ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

        p_id: Number,
        p_name: String,
        p_fk_category: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'categories'},

    }
    ,  {collection: 'products'});


module.exports = mongoose.model('products', ProductSchema);
```

**Category.js**

```
 var CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({

            c_id: Number,
            c_name: String,
            c_fk_event: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'events'},

        }
        ,  {collection: 'categories'});


    module.exports = mongoose.model('categories', CategorySchema);
```

**Event.js**

var EventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

```
        e_id: Number,
        e_name: String,
        e_fk_club_id: Number,

    }
    ,  {collection: 'events'});


module.exports = mongoose.model('events', EventSchema);
```

Suppose that I have : 3 Products, 2 categories and 2 events

Product 1 and Product 3 belongs to Category 1

Product 2 belongs to Category 2

Category 1 belongs to event 1

Category 2 belongs to event 2

Event 1 have club_id 1111

Event 2 have club_id 2222

This is an example
**Products**

```
{ 
"p_id": 001,
"p_name": "Product 1",
"p_fk_category": ObjectId("584fcfa4c50c7ab8ac31ba9f")
}

  { 
"p_id": 002,
"p_name": "Product 2",
"p_fk_category": ObjectId("584fcfa4c50c7ab8ac31baa0")
}

  { 
"p_id": 003,
"p_name": "Product 3",
"p_fk_category": ObjectId("584fcfa4c50c7ab8ac31ba9f")
}
```

**Categories**

```
{ 
"c_id": ObjectId("584fcfa4c50c7ab8ac31ba9f"),
"c_name": "Category 1",
"c_fk_event": ObjectId("584592bcf9fec37548e19485")
}

 { 
"c_id": ObjectId("584fcfa4c50c7ab8ac31baa0"),
"c_name": "Category 2",
"c_fk_event": ObjectId("584592bcf9fec37548e19486")
}
```

**Events**

```
{ 
"e_id": ObjectId("584592bcf9fec37548e19485"),
"e_name": "event 1",
"e_fk_club_id": 1111
}

  { 
"e_id": ObjectId("584592bcf9fec37548e19486"),
"e_name": "event 2",
"e_fk_club_id": 2222
}
```

The question is : In mongoose, how to obtain the products from e_fk_club_id that is equal to 1111, in other way how to obtain the product 1 and product 3 that there categories belong to the event 1 that its club_id equal to 1111.

I tried an example with deep populate but it dosen't work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As i get your problem you can use the $lookup aggregation query. I have write a query for you check it:

```
 db.events.aggregate([{"$match":{"e_fk_club_id":1111}},{"$lookup":{"from":"categories","localField":"e_id","foreignField":"c_fk_event","as":"categories"}},{"$unwind":"$categories"},{"$lookup":{"from":"products","localField":"categories.c_id","foreignField":"p_fk_category","as":"products"}}]).pretty()
```